# Firebase: flutter want to get a null value

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get data that is null in a Firebase database

```
stream: Firestore.instance
      .collection('resep')
      .where("email", isEqualTo: null)
      .snapshots(),
```

I want to get email data that is null

Comment: Hello man as per my experience if we are using firebase then firebase never accept null value in the parameter value

Comment: so how do we want to display data that has no contents sir?

Comment: https://pasteboard.co/IHHMIKz.png like this sir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation:

> where(dynamic field, { dynamic isEqualTo, dynamic isLessThan, dynamic
>   isLessThanOrEqualTo, dynamic isGreaterThan, dynamic
>   isGreaterThanOrEqualTo, dynamic arrayContains, bool isNull }) → Query
>   Creates and returns a new Query with additional filter on specified
>   field. field refers to a field in a document. [...]

There is a isNull property

Comment: can you implement it in my code?

i try : 
.where("email", isNull: )
but error

Comment: I cant test it right now but did you try .where("email",isNull:true)
and if you have some, share the error

Comment: thank you sir my code is correct, I have more questions, how do I want to ask? but the problem is different