# Firebase compound query with null value

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having trouble with a compound query that I've created for a flutter app:

```
final query = baseRef
    .collection('Jobs')
    .where('associatedAssetId', isEqualTo: job.associatedAssetID)
    .where('completionDate', isEqualTo: null)
    .orderBy('toDoDate', descending: false)
    .limit(1);
```

I've set up an index for it, but for some reason it is returning documents where the 'completionDate' field is NOT equal to null. Is there something that I'm missing about how compound queries work and the restrictions on them?

Comment: check the query where parameter because there is a isNull boolean parameter instead of isEqualTo

Comment: have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58973646/firebase-flutter-want-to-get-a-null-value

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much!